# Wordpress: Installation failed: Could not create directory. 'all-in-one-wp-migration' [even with CHMOD 777]

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

Information:

> **Using:** Wordpress: 4.9.7
>
> **System:** Mac
>
> **Server:** Vagrant: Ubuntu/trusty64

So I am rather new to development so please forgive me if this is basic.

I am trying to install the plugin: WP- All in One migration however I keep getting the error:

> Wordpress: Installation failed: Could not create directory. 'all-in-one-wp-migration'

In terminal I used:

```
 $ chmod -R a+rwx *
```

And gave every folder full permissions. If I right click and check permissions the plugins folder has **Read, Write and Execute** for everyone yet I am still getting the error.

All the other responses and posts for this keep saying it is a Chmod error which as you can see is not the case.

Is there any other reason I would not be able to download a plugin to my local machine and install it?

## Edit: Tried uploading ZIP in dashboard and getting problem with where child folders created are not getting parents permission.

Ok, for some reason when I upload the plugin from the dashboard into the uploads folder I get canot create /uploads/2018/08

so I go into the uploads folder and there is

```
- Uploads
-- 2018
```

however, 2018 does not have the correct permissions. So I set it and then run the install again. It creates:

```
- Uploads
-- 2018
---- 08
```

but then 08 does not have the correct permissions.

It seems new folders are not acquiring the parents permissions. Is there a setting for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have not got owner and mount options set up in vagrant.

In your vagrant folder, open your `Vagrantfile`.

You should see a line like:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "local/folder", "/var/www/"
```

Do you see a line beginning with:

```
owner: "www-data"
```

underneath that line???, if not, follow these steps:

Add a '`,`' after that line and then on a new line underneath add:

```
owner: "www-data", group: "www-data", :mount_options => ['dmode=777','fmode=777']
```

now in Terminal head to the vagrant home folder and run:

```
$ vagrant reload
```

Does that help?

Comment: This! Thank you soooooooo much. I'm quite new (junior) so not sure what i'm doing. Thank you again.

Comment: This solution worked for me, however, I had omit the folder permission options to get WP running (i.e. I add only the owner and group settings to the synced folder line).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a mac .execute these two line on terminal.

```
sudo chgrp -R _www /Path to your app directory

sudo chmod -R g+rw /Path to your app directory
```

Comment: My app directory? you mean plugins

Comment: ok tried it on plugins didnt work, tried it on root and also didnt do anything.